# Scaling in android game development, how to do it properly?

Tags: android, scale, scaling, image-scaling

So, recently me and my two teammates started on our exam project. Which is a basic 2D skijumping game.

We've done programming on android before but never in relation to games and we have the basic techniques down for creating animations using a thread and all that. But we seem to have a scaling issue.

Currently we have a background image in the drawable folder in the resolution 1920x1080, we are using BitmapFactory to scale the background image to the users screen size, which seems to be working fine it fits perfectly on all our 3 different smartphones.

Were creating an animation of the player sprite skiing down the hill and jumping off the edge, which looks very funny and works perfectly. For this I simply divided the screen width and height by 100 and used that percentage of either 1% screen width to move him at certain speeds on the x-axis and likewise on the y-axis with the 1% of the screen height.

It works on most phones but, for some reason it won't work on all of them? I don't understand why not? I mean the math should always work shouldn't it? On some phones he skies outside of the hill in the air and not on the proper trajectory. I don't get what I'm missing but I'm suspecting it has something to do with the screen format or something?

Can anyone enlighten me on this? Please keep in mind this is our first android game so were new at game dev.

And thanks for all your input if you have any in advance.

Comment: I would recommend  to use a game engine some are mentioned here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13071138/android-game-engine

Comment: move the player the same deltax/deltay no matter what screen you are using, only when drawing on the Canvas concat()enate the Canvas with a transformation Matrix different for each screen

Comment: I should have mentioned earlier, were not allowed to use any engines. The point is to code it ourselves from the ground up. @Pskink do you mind dropping an answer with perhaps a small example on how you go about doing this? If that could solve our problem I'd be more than grateful.

Comment: compute the transformation Matrix, if one screen is for example 1.5 bigger than other then its transformation Matrix should be scaled by factor 1.5, use that Matrix in onDraw by calling canvas.concat(matrix), draw original bitmap, draw player sprite and voila

Comment: So the first thing I should do in the draw method is create a matrix, set the scale of the matrix and add it to the canvas (only once Im assuming as the view is loaded?). Then draw all the images I need after that? If that's correctly understood, should I just load the original sized image and use it or should I still spend time resizing them for the screen?

Comment: create a Matrix in onSizeChanged where you know the View dims and yes, dont resize the Bitmap, just concat the matrix and do the drawing

Comment: Ok so this didn't work at all, our character isn't moving along the percentages of the screen at all after I've done this... he's much closer to acting normally using our old method. Does anyone have a different suggestion or can drop an elaborate answer with a small example? I'm not sure if I'm doing it right.

Comment: Wow I didn't know this issue was such a mystery? :/

Comment: @ObedMarsh so you are doing somwthing wrong, dont use any percentage, use constant dx, dy no matter what screen you are using

Comment: I appreciate your comments pskink, but I'd rather you didn't answer if your not going to elaborate and place a proper and detailed answer. Ill just wait and put bounty on it since it's apparently a major problem since noone knows.

Comment: i thought its so simple that does not require any detailed answer, but if you need it so see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
class V extends View implements Callback {

    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private Matrix mMatrix;
    private Handler mHandler;
    private float mX;
    private Paint mPaint;

    public V(Context context) {
        super(context);
        Resources res = getResources();
        mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.layer0);
        mMatrix = new Matrix();
        mHandler = new Handler(this);
        mHandler.obtainMessage(0).sendToTarget();
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setColor(0xff00ff00);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        RectF src = new RectF(0, 0, mBitmap.getWidth(), mBitmap.getHeight());
        RectF dst = new RectF(0, 0, w, h);
        mMatrix.setRectToRect(src, dst, ScaleToFit.CENTER);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.concat(mMatrix);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap,  0,  0, null);
        canvas.drawRect(mX, 20, mX + 20, 40, mPaint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(0);
        if (mX < mBitmap.getWidth()) {
            mX += 1.5f;
            mHandler.sendMessageDelayed(msg, 50);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "handleMessage stop");
        }
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: i forhot to add: make sure to place your image in res/drawable-nodpi folder